# append function in for-loop not working

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to wrote a code in the field of Sentiment Analysis. I have a dictionary (.txt)  in which words are rated, for example "good, 2" and "bad, -3". Now I want Python to count  together the positives and the negatives in a given sentence. My code snippet looks like this:

```
text =''

result = []
for sentence in sent_tokenize(text):
    pos = 0
    neg = 0
    for word in word_tokenize(sentence):
        score = Dictionary.get(word, 0)
        if score > 0:
            pos += score
            if score < 0:
                neg += score
                result.append([pos, neg])

for s in result: print(s)

print(result)
```

So I would want the result to look something like this: `[5, -6]`.
But I get an empty result: `[]`.
Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you define `sent_tokenize()` and `word_tokenize()`?

Comment: Earlier in the code, I defined it: sentence = word_tokenize(''.lower()) and sentences = sent_tokenize(''.lower())

Comment: That's calling the functions, not defining them.

Comment: sorry but I thought i definded them? How would defining look like?

Comment: If you are calling the functions, they should exist somewhere.  That might be `from ... import *` or `from ... import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize` or `def sent_tokenize(...):` and `def word_tokenize(...):`

Answer (score 2):

`score` cannot be less and greater than zero at the same time:

```
if score > 0:
    pos += score
    if score < 0:
        neg += score
        result.append([pos, neg])
```

Change your code to:

```
result = []
for sentence in sent_tokenize(text):
    pos = 0
    neg = 0
    for word in word_tokenize(sentence):
        score = Dictionary.get(word, 0)
        if score > 0:
            pos += score
        if score < 0:
            neg += score
    result.append([pos, neg])
```

Note the indention of `result.append([pos, neg])`. This should give you an new
pair of `pos, neg` for each sentence.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Unfortunately, I still get an empty Output... Do I have to change anythin else?

Comment: Just add some debug prints to see what values `sentence` and `word` have. Make sure you actual do the loops. ;)